# Verifying hCaptcha plugin submission on the server side

Tags: plugins, plugin-contactform

So I'm mostly a front-end developer working with craft. I'm using the craft contact form plugin and I'm trying to setup hcaptcha plugin to work with it. But I'm not sure how to implement the server side bit.

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin you're using is https://plugins.craftcms.com/craft-hcaptcha?craft4
then the documentation for using it (Documentation button on the plugin page) is available here:

https://github.com/c10d-dev/craft-hcaptcha/blob/main/README.md

There's several different ways to implement it in the twig template, depending on the desired outcome. Do let us know where you're stuck if you still need help

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is indeed the plugin! I've done everything but the server side bit. I'm not sure where to implement it and would love some assistance with that

Comment: Ah! Ok, the part where you verify it validated. "Verify the hCaptcha" from the docs.

Because you're using the Craft Contact Form I don't think you need to do this step, there's a note in the docs that you can just flip a toggle in the Contact Form plugin to have the hcaptcha plugin work with it. 

If you're doing a custom form, you'd need to put that server side validation code into your form's controller logic. The contact form plugin already takes care of that for you, if Im reading the docs correctly. Let me know if that helps!